# Power Query M Replace null with 0 inline inside Table.Pivot

Tags: powerbi, dax, m

I am trying to replace null value with 0, inline in a Table.Pivot statement.

I know that it can be done column by column after the Pivot, but this can fail due to the dynamic nature of the Table.Pivot columns.

Theoretical (not working code)

```
= Table.Pivot(#"Appended Query", List.Distinct(#"Appended Query"[coverage]), "coverage", "Value", List.Sum ?? 0)
```

Specifically, I am trying to determine the right syntax, function or similar solution to replicate the coalescing operator in the code above: **List.Sum ?? 0**

Answer (score 0):

if you're replacing values in a table, can't you just use something like this in PowerQuery?:

```
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type",null,0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Qty"}) in
#"Replaced Value"
```

Comment: Wouldn't this require an explicit list of columns ("Qty" in the above example)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `let-in` statement to create a function with this structure.

```
sum_or_0 = (x) => if List.IsEmpty(x) then 0 else List.Sum(x)
```

Not as elegant as an inline solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
= Table.Pivot(#"Appended Query", List.Distinct(#"Appended Query"[coverage]), "coverage", "Value", each if List.Sum(_) = null then 0 else List.Sum(_))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).